# How to transform dynamic type assertion to static one?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, typescript-typings, assertion

Is there a way to dynamically generate a const assertion in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) ?

I know you can create a `readonlyArray`assertion based on a staticly typed array, eg.

```
 const staticTyped = [1, 2, 3] as const // readonly [1, 2, 3]
 type TypeStatic = typeof staticTyped[number] // 1 | 2 | 3
```

Now that works as expected and elegantly. However, I need to create a large readonly array that's generated dynamically.

```
const generateNumRange = (from: number, to: number): number[] => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
     arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const dynamicTyped = [...generateNumRange(0, 255)] as const // readonly number[]
type TypeDynamic = typeof dynamicTyped[number] // number (oof)
```

---

Now I do understand where the issue lies, however I can't think of a way, that would allow me to return the `dyanmicTyped` as `[0, 1, 2, ..., 255]` rather than `number[]`.

Is there any way to do this / perhaps even more elegant solution to the problem altogether?

Comment: This is one of those questions which would be straightforward enough to answer if there were support for [circular conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980), which there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the type system doesn't exist at runtime. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480 Range types have been requested for a long time.

I don't see why type `number[]` is unacceptable, however if you *absolutely* need to infer the type, you will have to tell TS exactly what to do.

(I have seen library authors do this before, so maybe it's not so stupid? But hopefully this illustrates that you've reached one of the limits of the type system.)

```
type T1_2 = 0 | 1 | 2;
type T1_3 = T1_2 | 3;
type T1_4 = T1_3 | 4;

function generateNumRange(from: 0, to: 2): T1_2[];
function generateNumRange(from: 0, to: 3): T1_3[];
function generateNumRange(from: 0, to: 4): T1_4[];
function generateNumRange<T>(from: number, to: number): T[] {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const dynamicTyped = [...generateNumRange(0, 3)]
type TypeDynamic = typeof dynamicTyped[number] // 0 | 1 | 2 | 3

const dynamicTyped4 = [...generateNumRange(0, 4)]
type TypeDynamic4 = typeof dynamicTyped4[number] // 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Hopefully you can see that you could generate all this code in a simple for loop, up to any finite number you want.